# How to batch register interfaces without BasedOn method in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I’ve got a project under .NET Core. I want to register all repository interfaces to classes that implemented these interface without extending all interfaces from a base interface using Castle Windsor

I don’t want to use the code below:

```
container.Register(
FromAssemblyContaining<StudentRepository>()
    .BasedOn<IBase>()
    .WithService.Select((type, types) =>
        type.BaseType != null && type.Name.EndsWith(type.BaseType.Name)
            ? new[] { type.BaseType }
            : Enumerable.Empty<Type>()));
```

I want Castle Windsor to automatically detect all interfaces from the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code:

```
container.Kernel.Register(
    Classes.FromAssembly(typeof(StudentRepository).Assembly)
        .Where(Component.IsInNamespace(typeof(StudentRepository).Namespace, includeSubnamespaces: true))
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
        .LifestyleScoped());
```